# Avoiding key duplicates when merging data sets into single table

Tags: sql, t-sql, primary-key, pipeline, streamsets

I am trying to land our asset data from various countries (e.g. Spain, Sweden for now) into 1 table using StreamSets.

Considering that they both will have the same identity key, i.e. Spain will have a panel_ID = 1 and so will Sweden. To make my record set unique I will need to add an additional field such as CountryCode. However, this does not sit in our existing data. I will need to manually add this is (hard coded or automate through parameters). How can I achieve this using StreamSets (in the pipeline)?

Also, in general is this approach correct? Am I on the right tracks and what are some other things I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the source table into the code as an explicit column.  That would be something like:

```
select 'Sweden' as country, s.*
from sweden_data s
union all
select 'Spain' as country, s.*
from spain_data s;
```

You can save this into a table or just create a view constructed like this.

Answer (score 0):

The table name is available in the `jdbc.tables` attribute, which you can reference from [expression language](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Expression_Language/ExpressionLanguage_overview.html#concept_p54_4kl_vq) (EL) as `${record.attribute('jdbc.tables')}`. You can use an [Expression Evaluator](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/datacollector/UserGuide/Processors/Expression.html#concept_zm2_pp3_wq) to copy the attribute into a field that can be used in a compound key.